# form.fields_for do for a finite number of times

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, Product and ProductImage, and I'd like to offer the possibility to add up to 6 images to each product.

Product

```
has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy
```

while ProductImage

```
belongs_to :product
```

So far, my views are the following:

```
#products/_form.html.erb.
    <% @product.product_images.build %>
    <%= form_for(@product, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |product_form| %>
      <% if @product.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= product_form.label :title %><br />
        <%= product_form.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= product_form.label :description %><br />
        <%= product_form.text_area :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= product_form.label :price %><br />
        <%= product_form.text_field :price %>
      </div>
      <div id="product_images">
          <%= render :partial => 'product_images/form', :locals => {:form => product_form} %> 
        </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= product_form.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

and

```
#product_images/_form.html.erb
    <%= form.fields_for :product_images do |product_image_form| %>
        <div class="image">
            <%= product_image_form.label :image, 'Image:' %>
            <%= product_image_form.file_field :image %>
        </div>
        <% unless product_image_form.object.nil? || product_image_form.object.new_record? %>
        <div class="image">
            <%= product_image_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove:' %>
            <%= product_image_form.check_box :_destroy %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The question is: how do I force my partial form to print out 6 different file_fields, each with its own unique attribute name, e.g.:

```
name="product[product_images_attributes][0][image]"
name="product[product_images_attributes][1][image]"
```

and so on?

I mean, is that even possible or there is a better and different way to achieve such result?

I was thinking I could add as many fields with link_to and AJAX but I guess it's a lot easier for the user to have the six fields printed out and ready, instead of clicking a link each time in order to add a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images` in your Product model, you need something like the following in your ProdcutsController:

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  6.times { @product.product_images.build } # this will create 6 "blank product_images"
end

def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id]).includes(:product_images)
  (6 - @product.product_images.size).times { @product.product_images.build } # this will create as many "blanks" as needed
end
```

For new products, you `build` 6 new product images, for existing products you `build` only as many as you need in order to have 6.

Edit: Also remove the `<% @product.product_images.build %>` line from your products/_form.html.erb view since you are `build`ing the associated instances in your controller instead.

Comment: Teoulas, do you know where this sort of thing is documented? I really want to read more on how nested attributes are handled, but the documentations are really sparse on this subject.

Comment: You could always look at the code, if you want to know more about the internals of nested attributes. The concept is pretty simple, it just sets up some getter/setter methods for the associated model attributes. Here's the official documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to accept an unknown number of product images? For example allowing the user to have an 'add new product image button' that would create another product_images/form partial?

Comment: @turbo2oh, of course. You can either have a hidden set of inputs in your page, which you clone via javascript when you click on the add button, or you can fire an AJAX request on click and return a new set of inputs from your controller. There's a railscast about this which is a bit old: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 or if you have a pro account you can see the revised ones.